# Reading characters in a file. By 3 at a time.... in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that needs to find the word 'the' in a given file

```
    while ((c=reader.read())>=0)
    {
       if (c==116 && c+1==104 && c+2==101)
        return true;
    }
```

This is obviously wrong, although it correctly compares the value of `c` against the 116 (character code of "t"),
but then, `c+1` is obviously not the next character in the input,
so it's not comparing the right thing against 104 (character code of "h").
Ditto for `c+2` and 101 (character code of "e").

How can I read through the file looking for the word 'the'?

Note that I would prefer not to use arrays or fancy libraries. How can I do this?

Comment: Well since you use `Reader ` it seems the standard lib is OK, so use `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading 3 at a time will not be so easy. Consider for example the input "anthem". The first 3 characters would be "ant", the second "hem". The input contains "the", but it's split over two 3-char sequences.

It will be easier to read character by character,
for example following this algorithm:

- Read character by character with `reader.read()` until end of file, or until you find a `t`
- Read 1 more character and check:

  - Is it end of file? -> `return false`
  - Is it not `h`? -> continue to seek for the `t`
  - It's an `h`. Then read 1 more character and check:
  - Is it end of file? -> `return false`
  - Is it `e`? -> `return true`
- If the end of file is reached, `return false`

Here's one way to do it:

```
  boolean containsThe(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    int c1;
    while ((c1 = reader.read()) != -1) {
      if (c1 != 't') continue;

      int c2 = reader.read();
      if (c2 == -1) return false;
      if (c2 != 'h') continue;

      int c3 = reader.read();
      if (c3 == -1) return false;
      if (c3 == 'e') return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: This did it, I added ' ' before and after the word just to make sure I am actually referring the word the, and not just some random characters